# configure a regex path in yaml to exclude exceptions

Tags: php, regex, symfony, yaml, monolog

In monolog you can exclude path so that when an exception happens it doesn't get logged into prod.log

I wanted to exclude all logs from /items/* so I did the following:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler: file
            channels: ["!doctrine", "!event", "!security", "!request"]
            excluded_404s:
                - ^/items/
```

I wanted to exclude errors from `/items/19283712` and anything that has `/items/WHATEVERCRAPINHERE` . The documentation shown [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/logging/monolog_regex_based_excludes.html) details on how to do it.  I've tried the regex above and it doesn't seem to work. Why is this?

Comment: does adding a  -->  .*   <-- to the end of your pattern (turning on greedy matching) help?

Comment: @MBarnett so ^/items/.*

Comment: try `^/items/*` or `^/items/~`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following syntax `^/items/*`

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler: file
            channels: ["!doctrine", "!event", "!security", "!request"]
            excluded_404s:
                - ^/items/*
```